# How to return a UIImage from a function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, return

I am downloading an image (successfully) from Parse. My question is can I place the function that is getting the image in a separate class and just get the *UIImage* as the returned parameter? See example below.

In both the return statements in the function below I am getting this error:

[image]

```
func getImgfromParse() -> UIImage {

    //var imgFile: PFFile = PFFile()
    var query = PFQuery(className: "puzzledata")
    query.whereKey("wordAnswer", equalTo: "asd")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Found something")
            for object in objects {
                println(object.objectId)

                let pointsPerTile = object["pointsPerTile"] as String
                let timeAllowed = object["timeAllowed"] as String
                let wordAnswer = object["wordAnswer"] as String
                let wordJumbled = object["wordJumbled"] as String

                let imgFile = object["imageFile"] as PFFile


                imgFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                        return image
                    }

                })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end

            }
        }
        else {
            println("%@", error)
        }

        return UIImage(data: "profile.jpg")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your block

```
imgFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                        return image
                    }

                })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end
```

as you can see that the block provides two things imageData and error and expects you to return nothing i.e void but you are returning image from here, that's why it show's the error as 'cannot convert the expressions type `UIImage` to type void'.

I think rather than returning image, you should call a function with image as the parameter and save that image there/ do your stuff with the image as

```
imgFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                        saveImage(image)
                    }

                })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end
```

Comment: Your answer looks right but this function of mine is actually in a separate helper class than the actual viewcontroller class where I need this UIImage. How can I actually return a UIIMage from this function? I tried doing a var retImg: UIImage in the fucntion and assigning retImg = image, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is currect , I used same like this  , But here working fine ..  you can also this ..

```
    func imageResize (imageObj:UIImage, sizeChange:CGSize)-> UIImage{

     let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
    imageObj.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: sizeChange))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    return scaledImage
}
```

Answer source : - http://www.jogendra.com/2014/11/image-resize-in-swift-ios8.html

Please see this answer everything working fine